# What is the dataflow of using touchscreen with tslib?

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, arm, linux-device-driver

I don't understand how tslib works. Let's say I have a serial touchscreen, in my understanding the data flows in the following way:
`ts press -> serial port -> ts driver -> tslib -> device file (like /dev/input/eventX)`
Is it right? Or do I need to insert some code between `ts driver` and `tslib` so that they can communicate?

Comment: `/dev/input/eventX` is an alternative to `/dev/ttyS0` or whatever your serial port is.  A touch screen driver built into the kernel will have this type of name.  `tslib` can handler either type, in the way [Chris](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1933019/chris-mcharg) describes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tslib does not operate between the touch screen driver and the input device file - it accesses the device file on behalf of the application using it. The key data flow when using tslib is `device file -> tslib -> application`.

The application specifies the input device file (of the touch device) tslib should use with the `ts_open()` function and then uses other tslib functions to obtain the touch samples.

The tslib API is defined in [tslib.h](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib/blob/master/src/tslib.h) and there's a number of usage examples in the source under `tests` including the simple [ts_print.c](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib/blob/master/tests/ts_print.c).

Comment: The devices can also be specified with `environment` variables.