# can't get tslib to work with FT5x06

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, arm

I have a arm based board with embedded linux on it and I believe it has a FT5x06 touch screen controller  but seems like tslib has some problems with multitouch capacitive touch screen controllers. 
I cross compiled tslib with arm-linux-gcc4.5.1 and when after copying necessary files and setting necassary environmental variables for tslib on the target when I ran ts_calibrate a window shows up and it says that:

```
tslib: Selected device is not a touchscreen (must support ABS_X and ABS_Y events)
```

And it doesn't accept my touches. 
Now I think somehow I'm supposed to get tslib to work with the controller as a single touch device but I'm not sure how to do that or which file to change. Do I have to edit driver file in kernel and rebuild it too?

Do you have any ideas?

I want to use tslib as an input for my Qt4 program.

Comment: Related: [Tslib not creating device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397680/tslib-not-creating-device), [What is the dataflow of using touchscreen with tslib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351399/what-is-the-dataflow-of-using-touchscreen-with-tslib), [etc...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tslib)

Comment: What is the environment value `TSLIB_TSDEVICE`?  Ie, `ls -l ${TSLIB_TSDEVICE}`.  There are [various programs](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~whot/evtest/tree/evtest.c) to debug the FT2x06 driver, if it exists; although you should have source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tslib** will require the setup of several files and/or environment variables to work out of the box.  Here  is a sample of some environment variables,

```
 TSLIB_CONSOLEDEVICE=none
 TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
 TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/touch
 TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
 TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
```

Many variables are not needed to run Qt with **tslib**.  However, you will need the `TSLIB_TSDEVICE`, `TSLIB_CALIBFILE`, and `TSLIB_CONFFILE` to use with Qt.  The binaries *ts_calibrate* will use the `TSLIB_FBDEVICE` device to display some text.  This will then write a configuration to the `TSLIB_CALIBFILE`.

To determine the correct `TSLIB_TSDEVICE` to use, the files */sys/class/input/input*/name* can be examined.  The *name* should be something like **FT5202 Touchscreen**.  I use this information at boot time to soft link */dev/input/inputX* to */dev/input/touch* in the example above.  The *inputX* file may change as other input drivers are plugged into a system, such as a USB mouse, etc.  These file locations may depend on the type of *udev* or *mdev* you use for the */dev* directory population in user space.

The *ts.conf* file is a list of modules to load.  Here is an example for the 'Focal Tech' device,

```
module_raw input
module linear
```

**Tslib** is structured with several modules (shared libraries) which are loaded dynamically at run time.  Typically, these modules need to be loaded to */usr/lib/ts* and your kernel and filesystem (libc) need to support shared libraries.  Specifically, the **linear** module will use the output of the *ts_calibrate* program to map *touch co-ordinates* to *screen co-ordinates*.  This was much more useful with resistive touch technology where **x** and **y** [parameters may inter-mix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), including sheering, etc.

Note: it is possible to avoid this calibration step, which is highly desirable if you are manufacturing large quantities.

The numbers in the */etc/pointercal* are read into an array a[0] -> a[7]. The formula is like this,

```
x' = (a2 + a0 *x + a1 * y) / a6;
y' = (a5 + a3 *x + a4 * y) / a6;
```

For the capacitive case, there is no sheer.  Moreover, the values for the FocalTech devices seem to be restricted so that screen position (0,0) is touch position (0,0) and all the devices give the same maximum (x,y) values.  So the equations reduce to,

```
x' = (a1 * x) / a6;
y' = (a4 * y) / a6;
```

So the only purpose of the *pointercal* file is to map touch to screen co-ordinates **AND** the same for each device.  So you can manual hex-edit a *pointercal* file when you back solve the equations for the maximum screen positions.  You can get this information via the *ts_print_raw* binary.

Finally, the [Qt Mouse Calibration class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qws-mousecalibration.html) can be used to completely avoid **tslib**.  You only need code with the fixed three constants that will transform the co-ordinates.  You avoid the **tslib** package entirely.

Comment: `a[7]` is used as a pressure for devices that support it.  Qt4.8 can not support multi-touch features in devices like the FT5x06.

Comment: This answer assumes you have a working driver.  The touch driver is just an i2c interface and the protocol on the i2c needs to be decoded to provide the *linux input* system co-ordinates so that it looks like a *mouse device*.  I think that **Focal Tech** supplies a driver.

Comment: Well that was a pretty great answer. Actually the problem was with some variables specially TSLIB_TSDEVICE. But thank you for explaining the way that tslib works. Also I liked the  Qt Mouse Calibration class idea.

Comment: Hi @artlessnoise, I have same problem . I check all of tslib config on my nanopc_t2 friendlyARM, but my toch device not work. I found my device is /dev/input/event2 (I test it with `cat` command and it works).when I run `#ts_calibrate` it shows me this error `root@NanoPC-T2:~# ts_calibrate
TouchDevice: /dev/input/event1
xres = 1024, yres = 600
tslib: Selected device is not a touchscreen (must support ABS_X and ABS_Y events)
`and it does not work,BUT touch is works for default app on my device .

Comment: @H.Ghassami  Use `export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event2` to tell *tslib* to use *event2*.

Comment: @artlessnoise, thanks to reply, it solved with `export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts-mt.conf`, ts-mt is multi touch configure file for capacitive touch

Answer (score 0):

Your chip's driver simply uses ABS_MT_POSITION_X/Y event codes only. As of tslib 1.3, this is supported and tslib should work without problems. As of now, there is tslib-1.3-rc3 which should be safe to use. There won't be many changes until tslib-1.3 is released, see tslib's [project page](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib).